# Cannot find Bluetooth device with Swift code scanner on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, swift4

I am pairing with nonstandard Bluetooth device with my iOS app.

I found that iPhone detects only specific device classes. Tests were performed  on:
- Networking laptop - class: 0x02010c
- Wrist watch - class: 0xff0704

These devices were successfully found by build in Bluetooth scanner. I was also able to pair with them.

I am doing the scanning within my app and try pair with the device. Unfortunately after writing my Bluetooth scanner in Swift my phone doesn't detect the device.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {  
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var scanButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var devicesList: UITextView!
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    private var bluetoothOn: Bool!
    private var scanInProgress: Bool!

    //MARK: Initialization
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: NSNumber(value: false)])
        bluetoothOn = false
        scanInProgress = false
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func scanDevices(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if bluetoothOn && !scanInProgress {
            scanInProgress = true
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        } else {
            centralManager.stopScan()
        }
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("Bluetooth is On")
            bluetoothOn = true
         }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let line1 = "Name   : \(peripheral.name ?? "(No name)")"
        let line2 = "\nRSSI     : \(RSSI)"
        let line3 = "\nUUID     : \(peripheral.identifier)"
        var lineN = ""
        let lineEnd = "\n------------------------------------------------------\n"

        for ad in advertisementData {
            lineN.append("\nAD Data: \(ad)")
        }

        devicesList.text += "\n \(line1) + \(line2) + \(line3) + \(line4) + \(line5) +\(lineN) + \(lineEnd)"
        print(devicesList.text as Any)
    }
}
```

I expect my code finds the Bluetooth device exactly like built-in system scanner. Why my scanner cannot find the device? Is there a difference between built-in Bluetooth scanner and Swift API scanning solution?

Comment: That's because you are setting services to nil when you scan devices.

Comment: It detects all other devices around me with no issue. As far as I know, setting nil there let do the scanning for all devices in the area.

Comment: If you say so...

Comment: "If the serviceUUIDs parameter is nil, all discovered peripherals are returned regardless of their supported services" - Apple documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipherals

Comment: You can only discover BLE peripherals advertising GATT services with Core Bluetooth.  What profile is your peripheral using?

Comment: Currently I am using **Class: 0x02010c Service Classes: Networking Device Class: Computer, Laptop**. Using this I am able to pair with my device via built in Bluetooth scanner in settings. FYI I can change my device class to whatever would work.

Comment: I have tried also: **Class: 0xff0704
        Service Classes: Positioning, Networking, Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony, Information
        Device Class: Uncategorized, Wrist Watch** but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's impossible to find none BLE devices using CoreBluetooth framework. Apple simply blocked that possibility. 
The only alternative to do that is to user Private API to connect any Bluetooth device I want. The best solution to start with is to get [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) project from GitHub. It simply shows how to scan for Bluetooth devices using Private API.

This solution works just fine, unfortunately, it discredits the app from hitting the AppStore. This kind of solutions is not allowed by Apple so that the app will not pass the verification process.

Comment: i tried LightBlue and BlueCap apps but no one can find my printer in searching. what should we do now ?